# PDFlib - how can I clear attribute that was set by set_graphics_option()

Tags: pdflib

The code:

```php
$p->set_graphics_option('fillcolor={rgb 0 1 0} strokecolor={rgb 1 0 0} linewidth=2');
$p->rect(100, 300, 300, 200);
$p->fill_stroke();

$p->set_graphics_option('linewidth=1 strokecolor={rgb 1 0 0} linewidth=2');
$p->rect(100, 600, 100, 100);
$p->fill_stroke();
```

This will render two rectangles, both with red outline (stroke) and filled with green color.

The problem is that second rectangle still "remembers" fill color set by previous `set_graphics_option()` call - although most recent call does not define `fillcolor`.

**Questions**:

1. Is there something similar to `set_graphics_option('fillcolor=none')` to draw second rectangle as outline only?
2. Is there a command that works as opposite of `setcolor()` - that would unset current color?

**Important**:
I would like to use `fill_stroke()` to render both rectangles. I am aware that I can use either `fill()` or `stroke()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should encapsulate it with save restore:

```php
$p->save();
  $p->set_graphics_option('fillcolor={rgb 0 1 0} strokecolor={rgb 1 0 0} linewidth=2');
  $p->rect(100, 300, 300, 200);
  $p->fill_stroke();
$p->restore();

$p->save();
  $p->set_graphics_option('linewidth=1 strokecolor={rgb 1 0 0} linewidth=2');
  $p->rect(100, 600, 100, 100);
  $p->fill_stroke();
$p->restore();
```

when you set the same option multiple times within a *single* option list, the last one wins. In this sample, you set first `linewidth=1` and then `linewidth=2`, so the current line width is 2.

A option is always valid until you reset it, or the related scope stops.

> Is there something similar to set_graphics_option('fillcolor=none') to draw second rectangle as outline only?

When you don't want a fill the rectangle, please use stroke() instead. When you fill it, you get always the current color. And none is not a valid color.